# How to input text into tinceMCE editior using selenium/webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, tinymce, selenium-webdriver, wysiwyg

I am trying to automatically insert some text using [Selenium/Webdriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) into a text box created using [tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com/)

The text box is not a plain vanilla textbox so following is not working:

```
System.out.println("Finding text input element");
    WebElement element =  inputWebDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div/form/div/div/div[2]"));  //not working
    //WebElement element = inputWebDriver.findElement(By.tagName("form"));  // not working
    //WebElement element = inputWebDriver.findElement(By.id("tinymce"));  // not working

    System.out.println("Entering something in text input");
    element.sendKeys("Test text");
```

like it is working fine with plain text box https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted

Here is screenshot how the textarea element's location is seen in browser's element tab:
http://imageshack.com/a/img812/9341/1zau.png

**Note:** Through selenium, I am not able to get any element inside the 'embedded' html doc ( i get element not found error)

I have found a python equivalent to get done above, but, still looking to get it done in my java code:

```
browser.execute_script("tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('{}')".format(testTextVar))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing it. Here's an article you might want to have a look.

[Test WYSIWYG editors using Selenium WebDriver](http://yizeng.me/2014/01/31/test-wysiwyg-editors-using-selenium-webdriver/)

Code snippets below are not tested, only provide the logic in Java.

- Send keys directly. Same as Richard's answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21685050/1177636).

```java
inputWebDriver.switchTo().frame("input-data_ifr");
WebElement element = inputWebDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body"));
element.sendKeys("Send keys");
```

- Set innerHTML

```java
inputWebDriver.switchTo().frame("input-data_ifr");
WebElement element = inputWebDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body"));
(JavascriptExecutor)driver.executeScript("arguments[0].innerHTML = '<h1>Set text using innerHTML</h1>'", element);
```

- Use TinyMCE's native API

```java
// no need to switch iframe
(JavascriptExecutor)driver.executeScript("tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('<h1>Native API text</h1> TinyMCE')");
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, 2nd solution innerHTML one worked for me. Not sure, what is going on with 1st solution, i don't get any error, but also don't see the text being entered into the textbox.

Comment: @Watt: You might need to click body first to focus before sending keys.

Comment: 1st solution didn't work for me either, even with clicking the body first.  The innerHTML js call worked nicely.  The .NET equivalent, using the driver extension method: `driver.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].innerHTML = arguments[1]", driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body")), htmlValueToSet);`

Comment: @Yi Zeng: I was having problems with very slow performance working with tinyMCE and Selenium and tested your 3rd solution (native API). It's much faster than the first one (that I was using) and worked very well.

Answer (score 1):

The element is inside of an iframe.

You'll need to use:

```
inputWebDriver.switchTo().frame("input-data_ifr");
WebElement element = inputWebDriver.findElement(By.id("tinymce"));
System.out.println("Entering something in text input");
element.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "a");
element.sendKeys("Test text");
```

Then use the following to switch back to the top of the document when you're finished.

```
inputWebDriver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: Thanks!, I tried this code I get an exception saying `input_data_ifr` not found.. do I need to specify that its an `id`

Comment: @Watt sorry, I misspelled the ID.  I corrected it in the code.

Comment: Not a problem. +1, it is no more throwing error when I do  `element=inputWebDriver.findElement(By.id("tinymce"));` but it doesn't still input the text in textbox when I issue command  `element.sendKeys("Test text");`. Any ideas, what should I do differently?

Comment: @Richard: Typo? `switchTo().Frame` or `switchTo().frame`?

Comment: @user1177636 Not so much a typo as "I keep forgetting the syntax difference between c# and java".

Answer (score 0):

From @user1177636's answer above, I found that --in the Firefox driver-- I could only get the "Use TinyMCE's native API" option to work. However, that really was not what I wanted because that would overwrite everything in the textbox with the string provided to that API method. That was detrimental for me since I had a bunch of content in the editor I did not want to lose.

However, I am happy to inform you that simply using activeEditor.selection.setContent gets it to simply insert some text instead of overwriting all of it. Yeap, that extra "selection" is what I needed.

So, here is my solution, which is just a slight variation on @user1177636's tinyMce API on above and which prepends the word "changed! ":

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.setContent('changed! ')");
```

Do not forget that you'll need this import for that to work

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
```

Hope this helps someone else who might have the same predicament I had and saves them some time (not having to hunt as long as I did to discover this).