# Can't sendKeys() to TinyMCE with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, tinymce, selenium-webdriver, wysiwyg

I am using Selenium WebDriver in Eclipse and I am trying to insert text into a tinymce box on a web page. This is the code I am using.

```
//find tinymce iframe
editorFrame = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".col_right iframe"));

//switch to iframe
driver.switchTo().frame(editorFrame);
driver.findElement(By.className("mceContentBody")).sendKeys("YOOOO");
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

The cursor is blinking inside of the editor, however no text is sent. 
I have also tried this slight variation without any luck.

```
//find tinymce iframe
editorFrame = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".col_right iframe"));  

//switch to iframe
driver.switchTo().frame(editorFrame);
WebElement body = driver.findElement(By.className("mceContentBody"));
body.sendKeys("YOOOO");
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21684236/how-to-input-text-into-tincemce-editior-using-selenium-webdriver

Comment: Finally something worked! Thank you :) Is there anyway to select your comment as the answer?

Comment: I can add it as an answer, but I'd rather you upvote the answer you used on the other question.

Comment: I just tried to but my rep is too low to upvote.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, as what Richard says, this is a duplicate of [How to input text into tinceMCE editior using selenium/webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21684236/1177636).

For your specific code, I'd suggest

- Try different locator for `mceContentBody`, e.g use `By.cssSelector(".mceContentBody")`, `By.cssSelector("body")`, etc.
- Click the body first before sending keys.

```java
driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).click().sendKeys("YOOOO");
```

- Set innerHTML

```java
inputWebDriver.switchTo().frame("input-data_ifr");
WebElement element = inputWebDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body"));
(JavascriptExecutor)driver.executeScript("arguments[0].innerHTML = '<h1>Set text using innerHTML</h1>'", element);
```

- Use TinyMCE's native API

```java
// no need to switch iframe
(JavascriptExecutor)driver.executeScript("tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('<h1>Native API text</h1> TinyMCE')");
```

Further reading: [Test WYSIWYG editors using Selenium WebDriver](http://yizeng.me/2014/01/31/test-wysiwyg-editors-using-selenium-webdriver/)

Comment: I actually tried click before and that didn't work. The method with the javascript executor and setting the inner html in the other post worked. Thanks

Comment: how to get this JS code work for `redactor-editor`? I have already tried `driver.findElement(By.className("redactor-editor).sendKeys("hello world"));`

Comment: how to get this JS code work for `redactor-editor`. Its API is  [here](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/api/)??

Comment: the `inputWebDriver.switchTo().frame("input-data_ifr");` really helped me to find the mce body, without it I couldn't interact with the element

Comment: it's important to point out that you need to switch back to your default frame if you want to find other elements in yor page that aren't on this iframe.
To move back to the parent frame, you can either use `switchTo().parentFrame();` or if you want to get back to the main (or most parent) frame, you can use `switchTo().defaultContent();`

Answer (score 1):

Do this (c#)

```
yourWebDriver.ExecuteScript(string.Format("tinyMCE.getInstanceById('{0}').setContent('{1}');",yourWebElement.GetAttribute("id"), "hello world"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Snippet for writing to the tinymce editor:

**Note** - I will not suggest returning void for writing to editor method but keeping it here for simplicity -

```
public void writeTextToEditor(String text) {
   WebElement iframe = 
   driver().findElements(By.tagName(UtilTexts.HTML_ELEMENT_IFRAME)).get(0);

   driver().switchTo().frame(iframe);// something to look for when using timymce
   txt_editorBoxSupportArticle.click(); // if the focus is not on the editor window by default you have to perform click.
   txt_editorBoxSupportArticle.sendKeys(text);

   getDriverForCurrentThread().switchTo().defaultContent();
}
```

Snippet for reading from the tinymce editor:

```
public String readTextFromEditor() {
    @FindBy(how = How.ID, using = ("tinymce"))
    private WebElement txt_editorBoxSupportArticle;

    WebElement iframe = 
    driver().findElements(By.tagName(UtilTexts.HTML_ELEMENT_IFRAME)).get(0);

    driver().switchTo().frame(iframe);
    String articleDesc = txt_editorBoxSupportArticle.getText();
    getDriverForCurrentThread().switchTo().defaultContent();
    return articleDesc;
}
```

Code snippets above are tested. Although I will also suggest trying TinyMCE's native API.

Please share your thoughts if you find it useful.

Thanks