# Entering text to a <p> tag with selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I've spent the last hour or so trying to find an element on the screen to add text too. I've managed with the title but can't seem to add the body text.

```
<body id="tinymce" class="mce-content-body content post-type-post post-status-auto-draft post-format-standard locale-en mceContentBody wp-editor wp-autoresize html5-captions has-focus" contenteditable="true" data-id="content" style="overflow-y: hidden;">
    <p>
        <br data-mce-bogus="1">
    </p>
```

When I search the element it directs me to the `<p>` tag. 

I'm stumped.

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("tinymce")).SendKeys("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit");
```

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21684236/how-to-input-text-into-tincemce-editior-using-selenium-webdriver.

Comment: Thanks for the link struggling to follow it if im honest. Seems the same problem im having however I can't seem to locate the add post body on wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by below way. just change the syntax as code is in java

```
driver.findElement(By.id("tinymce")).findElement(By.tagName("p")).sendKeys("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit");
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Doesn't appear to be finding the "tinymce" at the moment it runs fine though

Comment: @Peter that's because of the iframe, it is most likely in the iframe that you need to switch to.

Comment: @alecxe I've no idea what that means? I'm pretty new to all this.

Comment: driver.switchTo().frame(0); .. He mean to say to switch on frame first and then use my code .... Read about frame switch .. There are many way to switch to frame

Comment: driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.Id("tinymce")).FindElement(By.TagName("p")).SendKeys("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"));

This comes up with 2 errors now. I'm clearly not getting it just yet.

Comment: driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.Id("content_ifr")).SendKeys("Lorem Ipsum")); If I take out the send keys part it does seem to find the location now. However when I add the sendkeys I have a build issue.

Answer (score 0):

Done it. in this case here was my fix. Which pretty much goes with what you guys said with a few tweaks.

```
        driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.Id("content_ifr")));
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("tinymce")).SendKeys("your data");
```