# Entering text with Selenium IDE in TinyMCE working when clicking 'Find' button, but not when running

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am trying to use Selenium IDE to enter text in a TinyMCE text field, and have come across some code that seems like it will work, but so far it's only half-working.

What I have is:

```
...
    <tr>
    <td>selectFrame</td>
    <td>id=message_ifr</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>runScript</td>
    <td>document.getElementById('tinymce').innerHTML=&quot;I am typing into the Draft Section, I hope&quot;;</td>
    <td>Editor</td>
</tr>
...
```

When I run the first command, it selects the iFrame, but nothing happends when I run the second command, nothing happens.  However, when I click the 'Find' button on the target, the text is entered in the TinyMCE text area, so it looks like it's working on some level.

Anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Code came from this page:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/selenium-users/ide$20tinymce/selenium-users/0FBmA6TUQ4s/2kaAdeU7CgAJ

Answer (score 0):

It is tricky to enter text into TimyMCE text boxes. There are two steps involved in handling this task using selenium.

1. Switch to the frame in which the text box is present
2. Using Javascriptexecutor to enter the text into the same.

Please refer to the similar link in stackoverflow. 
[How to input text into tinceMCE editior using selenium/webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21684236/how-to-input-text-into-tincemce-editior-using-selenium-webdriver)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that, but it was the Selenium IDE version that I'm having to use, so entering large amounts of Java will not work here.

Answer (score 0):

This is ugly but it will work (based on the example at https://www.tinymce.com/)

```
<tr>
    <td>runScript</td>
    <td>tinymce.setActive(tinymce.get('mce_0'));tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('&lt;h1&gt;some text&lt;/h1&gt; TinyMCE');</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

And if you're wondering what id to use (in this example in the .get I used mce_0) you can click into your tinymce text box and then run this in the console: `tinymce.activeEditor.id;`